# ClaimsAuthorizationManager could not load type issue WIF 3.5

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, .net-3.5, wif

I have written a custom claims authorization manager but whenever I try to start the application I get the following error

**The value of the property 'type' cannot be parsed. The error is: Could not load type 'MyCustomClaimsAuthorizationManager'.**

I am using WIF 3.5 in SharePoint 2010. So .NET 3.5.

My config section looks like

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
    <service saveBootstrapTokens="true">
        <claimsAuthorizationManager type="MyCustomClaimsAuthorizationManager" />
        <audienceUris />
        <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPPassiveIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
        <securityTokenHandlers>
            <clear />
            <add type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSaml11SecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
                <samlSecurityTokenRequirement>
                    <nameClaimType value="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2009/08/claims/userid" />
                </samlSecurityTokenRequirement>
            </add>
            <add type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPTokenCache, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
        </securityTokenHandlers>
        <federatedAuthentication>
            <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="false"
                          issuer="https://none"
                          realm="https://none" />
            <cookieHandler mode="Custom"
                           path="/">
                <customCookieHandler type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPChunkedCookieHandler, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
            </cookieHandler>
        </federatedAuthentication>
    </service>
</microsoft.identityModel>
```

My authorization manager looks like:

```
public class MyCustomClaimsAuthorizationManager : Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the principal specified in the authorization context is authorized to perform
    /// action specified in the authorization context on the specified resoure
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pec">Authorization context</param>
    /// <returns>true if authorized, false otherwise</returns>
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    #endregion Public Methods
}
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance
Pete

Answer (score 0):

So... it turns out this was a simple error on my part and the "type" attribute of the "claimsAuthorizationManager" must have the full assembly information as well.

E.g.

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
<service saveBootstrapTokens="true">
    <claimsAuthorizationManager type="MyCustomClaimsAuthorizationManager, assemblyName, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234gfdsa5465465" />
    <audienceUris />
    <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPPassiveIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <securityTokenHandlers>
        <clear />
        <add type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSaml11SecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
            <samlSecurityTokenRequirement>
                <nameClaimType value="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2009/08/claims/userid" />
            </samlSecurityTokenRequirement>
        </add>
        <add type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPTokenCache, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    </securityTokenHandlers>
    <federatedAuthentication>
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="false"
                      issuer="https://none"
                      realm="https://none" />
        <cookieHandler mode="Custom"
                       path="/">
            <customCookieHandler type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPChunkedCookieHandler, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
        </cookieHandler>
    </federatedAuthentication>
</service>
```